# Why doesn't calling a string method (such as .replace or .strip) modify (mutate) the string?

Tags: python, string

I tried this code to do simple string replacement:

```
X = "hello world"
X.replace("hello", "goodbye")
```

Why doesn't `X` change, from `"hello world"` to `"goodbye world"`?

Answer (score 261, accepted):

This is because **strings are immutable in Python**.

Which means that `X.replace("hello","goodbye")` returns **a copy of `X` with replacements made**. Because of that you need to replace this line:

```
X.replace("hello", "goodbye")
```

with this line:

```
X = X.replace("hello", "goodbye")
```

More broadly, **this is true for all Python string methods that change a string's content**, e.g. `replace`,`strip`,`translate`,`lower`/`upper`,`join`,...

**You must assign their output to something if you want to use it** and not throw it away, e.g.

```
X  = X.strip(' \t')
X2 = X.translate(...)
Y  = X.lower()
Z  = X.upper()
A  = X.join(':')
B  = X.capitalize()
C  = X.casefold()
```

and so on.

Comment: Pedantic point: strings can be mutated for `x += 'a'` special case, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40996908/6260170

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Looks like you are right, but from outside it does not have a real mutability effect - some implementations check if this is really used, and if not (so mutability would not be observed), it would actually mutate. Is that true?

Comment: @Tadeck Well I think it is *real* but it's merely a CPython optimisation and not directly relevant here (that's why I said I was being pedantic)

Answer (score 0):

All string functions as `lower`, `upper`, `strip` are returning a string without modifying the original. If you try to modify a string, as you might think `well it is an iterable`, it will fail.

```
x = 'hello'
x[0] = 'i' #'str' object does not support item assignment
```

> There is a good reading about the importance of strings being immutable: [Why are Python strings immutable? Best practices for using them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680080/why-are-python-strings-immutable-best-practices-for-using-them)