# string.upper(<str>) and <str>.upper() won't execute

Tags: python, string, operation

I have the following bit of code:

```
def test():
    fragment = ''
    fragment = raw_input('Enter input')
    while fragment not in string.ascii_letters:
        fragment = raw_input('Invalid character entered, try again: ')
    fragment.upper()
    print fragment*3
```

However when I run it, say for an input value of `p`, `fragment` gets printed as 'ppp' - all lower case, i.e. the `fragment.upper()` line does not run. The same thing happens if I replace that line with `string.upper(fragment)` (and adding *import string* at the beginning). Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't calling a Python string method do anything unless you assign its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). So functions like `str.upper()` will not modify `str` but return a new string.

```
>>> name = "xyz"
>>> name.upper()
'XYZ'
>>> print name
xyz  # Notice that it's still in lower case.
>>> name_upper = name.upper()
>>> print name_upper
XYZ
```

So instead of `fragment.upper()` in your code, you need to do `new_variable = fragment.upper()`and then use this `new_variable`.

Comment: Don't misuse `str` for your variables.

Answer (score 7):

You're not realizing that strings in Python are immutable and that string methods and operations return new strings.

```
>>> print 'ppp'.upper()
PPP
```

Comment: #this. u  have to do something like

fragment == fragment.upper()

had the same problem with a filter using .replace... it took my very long till i understood this. now i wont forget it again :D

Answer (score 3):

String is a immutable object, so when you call

```
string.upper()
```

python would make a copy of the string, and when you come back call

```
print string
```

, it would be the original string, which is lower case. So when you need its upper case version, you have to say:

```
print string.upper()
```

Comment: `string` is a great library. Don't use it for variable names.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. I suppose I won't be able to assign 'string' as a name to a variable :)