# How can I insert multiple new line characters within a file using python?

Tags: python, return, character, fasta

I have a fasta file that does not contain any return characters. The file looks something like this:

```
>Sequence_ID(Num1)AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTTTTAAAAA>Seqence_ID(Num2)AAAAAAATTTTTTTAAAATTTAATTTAATTATTAT>Sequence_ID (Num3)AAATTTTATTAGGAGGGA and so on for many lines.
```

I would have been trying to make a python program that would read this file, and insert a new line character at the end of every sequence ID and sequence itself. I am hoping the output would look like this:

```
>Sequence_ID(Num1) AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTTTTAAAAA
>Seqence_ID(Num2) AAAAAAATTTTTTTAAAATTTAATTTAATTATTAT
>Sequence_ID (Num3)AAATTTTATTAGGAGGGA
```

So far I have this:

```
input = open('LG_allseqs.txt', 'r')

output = open('LG_Seqs.txt', 'w')

for line in input.readlines():

    if line == '>':
        output.write('\n' + line)
    else:
        output.write(line)
```

There is no error messages (the syntax is "correct") however I do not generate the particular output I want. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: str.replace(old,new) will help
check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/python-string-replace

Comment: How large is the FASTA file? Can the entire file be read into memory?

Comment: The fasta file is not large, it can be read into memory

Comment: For the output to be valid FASTA you need `\n` after the ID, as well.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are confusing "lines" with "characters".  If everything is on a single line, then read it as a single string (using `read`, not `readlines`), and then write out \n-separated lines:

```
inputtext = input.read()  # 'input' is not a very good name for a variable, btw
output.write('\n'.join('#'+line for line in inputtext.split('>')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not replacing any characters in your loop. Try the following loop:

```
for line in input.readlines():
    output.write(line.replace('>', '\n'))
```

You mentionned in the comment below you wanted to keep the '>' character. Try the following loop to do that:

```
for line in input.readlines():
    output.write(line.replace('>', '\n>'))
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much. That separated the sequences as I hoped it would. The only problem is that I do not intend to replace the '>' character, I was hoping to keep that character in the beginning of each line. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: output.write(line.replace('>', '\n>'))

Comment: don't you mean output.write(line.replace('>', '\n>')) ?

Comment: @flexy The original question did not require the > be kept. That is why there are two code blocks. Maybe I am misunderstanding what you mean?

Comment: As far as I see it, the question requiered it to stay in, look at the quoted desired output. The '>' character is actually part of the FASTA fileformat, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

This could be solution for you:

```
open('LG_Seqs.txt', 'w').write( 
     open('LG_allseqs.txt', 'r').read().replace(">", "\n>") )
```

and demo of replace:

```
>>> x = """Sequence_ID(Num1)AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTTTTAAAAA>Seqence_ID(Num2)AAAAAAATTTTTTTAAAATTTAATTTAATTATTAT>Sequence_ID (Num3)AAATTTTATTAGGAGGGA and so on for many lines."""
>>> print x.replace(">", "\n>")
>Sequence_ID(Num1)AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATTTTTTTAAAAA
>Seqence_ID(Num2)AAAAAAATTTTTTTAAAATTTAATTTAATTATTAT
>Sequence_ID (Num3)AAATTTTATTAGGAGGGA and so on for many lines.
```