# This code snippet is not working for both upper case and lower case letters

Tags: python

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
         "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
         "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
         "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
         "x": 8, "z": 10}

def scrabble_score(word):
    count=0
    word.lower()
    print word
    for char in word:
        count=count+score[char]
    return count
```

I basically have to take the input word and count its score depending on the dictionary.

Comment: You can do the loop much more easily: `count = sum(score[char] for char in word)`.

Comment: Note that you can express `scrabble_score(word)` as simply `sum(score[char] for char in word.lower())`

Comment: Duplicate of [Why doesn't calling a Python string method do anything unless you assign its output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This modified code will work:

```
def scrabble_score(word):
    count=0
    word = word.lower() #assign the result of word.lower() to word
```

`word.lower()` returns the modified word, it doesn't modify the string *inplace*. Strings are ***immutable*** in Python. The fact that `.lower()` returns a string is defined as such:

```
>>> help(str.lower)
Help on method_descriptor:

lower(...)
    S.lower() -> string

    Return a copy of the string S converted to lowercase.
```

Answer (score 5):

[`str.lower()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.lower) returns a copy of the string - it does not change the original string. Try this:

```
word = word.lower()
```

Answer (score 4):

The `scrabble_score` function can be expressed more simply like this:

```
def scrabble_score(word):
    return sum(score[char] for char in word.lower())
```

In Python, the idiomatic way to express an iteration is to use generator expressions (as in the above code) or list comprehensions.

Regarding your current problem, as has been pointed in the other answers, the `lower()` method (and all other string methods for that matter) don't modify the string in place, so you have to either reassign the returned value or use it immediately, as shown in my answer.