# replacing line in a document with Python

Tags: python

I have the following file and I would like to replace *#sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))* 
with *sys.path.extend(['path1', 'path2'])*

```
import sys
import os

# If extensions (or modules to document with autodoc) are in another directory,
# add these directories to sys.path here. If the directory is relative to the
# documentation root, use os.path.abspath to make it absolute, like shown here.
#sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))

# -- General configuration ------------------------------------------------
```

However, the following code does not change the line.

```
with open(os.path.join(conf_py_path, "conf.py"), 'r+') as cnfpy:
    for line in cnfpy:
        line.replace("#sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.')))",
                    "sys.path.extend(%s)\n" %src_paths)
        cnfpy.write(line)
```

How is it possible to replace the line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/python-string-replace

Comment: the problem can be demonstrated without opening a file. please strive to create a minimal example.

Comment: We have two problems here: 1. Not saving the result of `line.replace()`, 2. Not reading and writing a file opened in `r+` mode correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) to change a string in-place within a file:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
    print(line.replace(string_to_replace, new_string))
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to do *print line.replace(...,...),*

Comment: @user977828, right. I've edited the answer.