# Remove spaces from user input string in Python

Tags: python, string, whitespace, user-input

how can I remove whitespaces from within a user input string? 
Can't I use `.replace(" ","")`? it didn't work for me.
My code:

```
>>>p=raw_input ("Enter phrase:\n")    
>>>p.replace(" "."")
```

It still outputs user input phrase WITH spaces..what am I doing wrong?Please help.

Comment: 1. It is a `,` (comma) and not a `.` (period) that separates the arguments to the function 2. `str.replace` is not inplace. You need to assign it back

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out

Comment: My bad, i had a comma in my code. Still didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

since strings are immutable in python, `str.replace` returns a new string, it does not modify the existing string

```
p = p.replace(" ","")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use replace, but you have to assign its return to the variable

```
>>>p=raw_input ("Enter phrase:\n")

>>>p=p.replace(" ","")
```