# Replacing white space inside a list of strings in python

Tags: python, for-loop, whitespace

I'm trying to find a really simple way of removing the white space in a list of strings. For I want to turn the list age:

```
age = ['15', '23 years', '21']
```

into

```
age = ['15', '23years', '21']
```

Notice how the space between '23' and 'years' was removed? I'm not sure why my if statement below doesn't work:

```
for x in age:
     x.replace(" ", "")
```

What am I missing here? I took a step back and tried to remove the whitespace from a simple string:

```
test = 'hi hi hi'
```

and the following code works for removing the whitespace:

```
test.replace(" ", "")
```

returning this when 'test is called:

```
'hihihi'
```

So why can't I just add a for loop to iterate over a list of strings and remove the whitespace like I did above? What code would allow me to solve my problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `replace` doesn't change the string, it only returns new one.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9189172/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe we should probably consider questions like this one a dupe of the one you've linked.

Comment: @alecxe we certainly should - I'd vote as such if I had any votes left!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to modify the list, as `str` objects are immutable:

```
age = [x.replace(" ", "") for x in age]
```