# Python programming: printing an input in upper case

Tags: python

I can print a string in upper case but can't get it to work when i ask the user to input a sentence. I have tried this code:

```
sntc = str(input ("Please enter a sentence."))
str.upper (sntc)
```

and this:

```
sntc = input ("Please enter a sentence.")
str.upper (sntc)
```

but none of these seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: This is clearly not caused by a typo, and also clearly reproducible behavior. The close reason is invalid so I'm voting to re-open.

Comment: @thebjorn to be fair, it should have been closed originally as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out

Comment: @snakecharmerb indubitably, and a dupe-close is infinitely more useful (both for OP and people who find the question later).

Answer (score 2):

Python strings are immutable, so string methods like `str.upper()` return a new string.

So in your case, you would need to do:

`upper_string = sntc.upper()`

Comment: Or just call `upper` right from the `input` prompt. `input().upper()`

Comment: @idjaw that would work too, but I wanted to be clear that we are creating a new string.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't modifying the string when you use `.upper()` because strings are immutable.  You need to assign something to what `.upper()` returns:

```
sntc = input("Please enter a sentence.")
sntc = sntc.upper()
```

or the shortened form:

```
sntc = input("Please enter a sentence.").upper()
```