# Create a program that asks the user for a string and then prints the string in upper case

Tags: python-3.x

EDIT: I tried the code lines in the link to other questions that were similar, however the programs did not execute correctly

I am a full-on noob trying to complete some free online resources for self improvement and learning.  I am using University of Waterloo's 'Python from scratch' and CS circles course   I have tried to answer this question and cannot seem to:
Write a program that asks the user for a string and then prints the string in upper case.
I have tried:

```
print (str(input()).upper)
```

AS WELL AS

```
text = input()
print (text.upper)
```

AND

```
print(input().upper())
```

all programs run, but dont have correct output so I dont know what I am missing here. It's likely obvious and I may feel foolish

I would love to learn and move on, thanks for any assistance!

this is 'Python from scratch' 2.11 problem 'g' (7th problem in set)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python programming: printing an input in upper case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36291703/python-programming-printing-an-input-in-upper-case)

Comment: Thank you Dave and Matias, Matias, I rejected your edits by accident, very sorry! I am trying to figure out how to accept your edits, however it looks like Dave did that already, thank you very much Dave.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close, the following works:

```
input.upper()
```

so,  `print(input.upper())`

should work for you.

Comment: Hi Dave, here is what I got when I ran that                                                      Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'upper'

Comment: What version of Python are you using?   The code sample has been tested in Python 3.4 within PyCharm

Comment: Hi Dave, it is the compiler on the site at Uni of Waterloo

Comment: I am downloading pycharm and will run items here in the future

Answer (score 1):

```
text=input()
print(text.upper())
```

Comment: upper() is a function and it needs to have () in the end of it

Comment: I really really appreciate your input, however it is not working, could it be an issue with the site/compiler I am using while I learn on the Uni of Waterloo website?

Comment: well it should definitely work. Try to check the compiler in this way:

Comment: text="Hi!" print(text)

Comment: this should just print Hi!. if this doesn't work, then something is wrong with the website. honestly, I do not know why you use this website to learn Python. there are many other great sources to learn it and you can download a free text editor (compiler) and write code there which will be easier and feel more real probably

Answer (score 1):

```
print(input().upper())
```

This should have worked for you in Python 3.x