# How to remove "\n" of a string in python3?

Tags: python

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    string =[' \n            Boeing Vancouver\n          ', '\n          Airbus\n        ', '\n          Lockheed Martin\n        ', '\n          Rolls-Royce\n        ', '\n          Northrop Grumman\n        ', '\n          BOMBARDIER\n        ', '\n          Raytheon\n        ']
    for item in string:
        item.replace("\n"," ")
        item.strip()
    print(string)
```

the output is the same as the input, why?

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: `string = [s.strip() for s in string]`

Comment: `[a.replace('\n',' ').strip() for a in string]` will give you a new modified list.

Comment: [Somewhat dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40444787/python-strip-method-not-working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String are imutable in python. You can simply strip the leading or trailing whitespaces using list comprehension to make new list.

```
[x.strip() for x in string]
```

Comment: On mobile pleaae mind the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to review [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) again:

> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

In other words, `item.replace("\n"," ")` on its own does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) like:

#### Code:

```
[s.replace("\n", " ") for s in a_string]
```

#### Test Code:

```
a_string = [' \n            Boeing Vancouver\n          ',
          '\n          Airbus\n        ',
          '\n          Lockheed Martin\n        ',
          '\n          Rolls-Royce\n        ',
          '\n          Northrop Grumman\n        ',
          '\n          BOMBARDIER\n        ',
          '\n          Raytheon\n        ']


print([s.replace("\n", " ") for s in a_string])
```

#### Results:

```
['              Boeing Vancouver           ', 
 '           Airbus         ', 
 '           Lockheed Martin         ', 
 '           Rolls-Royce         ', 
 '           Northrop Grumman         ', 
 '           BOMBARDIER         ', 
 '           Raytheon         ']
```