# newline character problems with Python (strip)

Tags: python, newline

If I write

```
f = open("file.csv","r")
    if f.mode == "r":
        cols = []
        snames = []
        svals = []
        rows = f.readlines()
        for x in rows:
            x.strip("\n")
            cols = x.split(",")
            snames.append(cols[0])
            svals.append(cols[1])
```

then svals still has the \n characters I dont want e.g. '20.43256639\n'

but if I do this instead, then svals shows the correct values without the \n

```
for x in rows:
    cols = x.split(",")
    snames.append(cols[0])
    svals.append(cols[1].strip("\n"))
```

svals DOES have the right values e.g. '20.43256639'

Comment: The line `x.strip("\n")` have no effect. You probably wanted to do `x = x.strip("\n")`. By the way whitespaces are already the default, so just do `x = x.strip()`

Comment: @Tomerikoo `'\n'` is _not_ the default. The default is all whitespace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python .strip method not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40444787/python-strip-method-not-working)

Comment: You're not wrong, but `x.strip()` vs `x.strip("\n")` vs `x.rstrip()` certainly makes a difference if you're reading data where indentation matters (such as, oh, say, Python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x.strip("\n")
```

doesn't modify `x` in-place (since strings are immutable anyway).
Try

```
x = x.strip("\n")
```

instead, or to put it all a little more succinctly:

```
with open("file.csv","r") as f:
    snames = []
    svals = []
    for x in f:
        sname, sval = x.strip().split(",", 1)
        snames.append(sname)
        svals.append(sval)
```