# Can't find and replace words in a text using dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

So my python script should get a text file and basically translate it using a dictionary, but I'm stuck and can't get it to work, it runs but doesn't do anything effectively.

1st file (which was given):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bead import Ford

szotar = {"The" : "A", "sun": "nap", "shining" : "süt", "wind" : "szél", "not" : "nem", "blowing" : "fúj"}

fd = Ford(szotar)
fd.fordit("teszt.txt", "kimenet.txt")
```

And my attempt on that Ford class:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Ford:
    def __init__ (self, values = dict(), keys = dict()):
        self.values = values
        self.keys = keys

    def fordit(self, inFile, outFile):
        self.inFile = inFile
        self.outFile = outFile
        try:
           with open("teszt.txt", 'r') as inFile:
               text = inFile.read()
        except:
            print "Nincs input file!"

        for key in dict().iterkeys():
            text.replace(key,dict()[key])

        outFile = open("kimenet.txt", "w")
        outFile.write(text)
        outFile.close()
```

I am new to python, so every bit of advice and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any error message? (Please post it.) Otherwise, explain what "_doesn't do anything effectively_" means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't calling a Python string method do anything unless you assign its output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out)

Comment: Actually, there is more than that wrong with your code. You are iterating over `dict().iterkeys()` but that is an empty dict, so the for-loop never iterates. Also, `dict()[key]` is guaranteed to throw a `KeyError` because once again, you are creating an empty dict on the fly and trying to indext into it

Answer (score 1):

The issue probably lies in the `Ford` class starting at your `__init__` function:

```
def __init__ (self, values = dict(), keys = dict()):
    self.values = values
    self.keys = keys
```

What you're doing there is giving Python default values for `value` and `keys`, which will both be empty dictionaries if not provided when the function is initialized. Since you're initializing `Ford` with `fd = Ford(szotar)`, you're basically telling Python that `values` is the `szotar` dictionary, but `keys` is a separate empty dictionary.

Then, in `fordit` you initialize the function with parameters `inFile` and `outFile`, but then read from and write to files without ever using these parameters.

Finally, even if the line `text.replace(key,dict()[key])` is getting the right input (which I'm not sure it is), it is not actually editing `text` — it'd have to look like `text = text.replace(key,dict()[key])` instead. This line alone would mean the difference between the output file having the text with the replacements or without them.

I'd rewrite the whole file where you define the `Ford` class to look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Ford():
    def __init__ (self, words):
        self.words = words

    def fordit(self, inFile, outFile):
        with open(inFile, 'r') as iF:
            text = iF.read()

        for key in self.words:
            text = text.replace(key, self.words[key]) 

        with open(self.outFile, "w") as oF:
            oF.write(text)
```

You can also avoid having to call the subfunction `fordit` manually, by having it look like this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Ford():
    def __init__ (self, words, inFile, outFile):
        self.words = words
        self.inFile = inFile
        self.outFile = outFile
        self.fordit()

    def fordit(self):
        with open(self.inFile, 'r') as iF:
            text = iF.read()

        for key in self.words:
            text = text.replace(key, self.words[key]) 

        with open(self.outFile, "w") as oF:
            oF.write(text)
```

And then the first file would just need this one line at the bottom, instead of the two you currently have:

```
Ford(szotar, "teszt.txt", "kimenet.txt")
```

---

Note that the string replace method will replace *all* occurrences of a substring in a string. That means that `sun` would turn into `nap`, but `sunny` would also turn into `nappy`.