# Using str.replace method changes nothing in the original string

Tags: python

I need to compare paths.
In a textile, I get paths like:

```
'C:\\\\Windows\\\\System32\\\\kernel32.dll'
```

The other path I get from the command line.

To compare the two strings I tried:

```
while path.find('\\') != -1:
    path.replace('\\\\','\\', 1)
```

but this changes nothing.
Also the builtin functions `os.path.normpath()` and `os.path.realpath()` don't remove the backslashes.
How to remove the backslashes from the string?

Comment: path = path.replace('\\\\','\\', 1)

Comment: did you try ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160752/removing-backslashes-from-a-string-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't calling a Python string method do anything unless you assign its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
path = path.replace('\\\\','\\', 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# you need to assign the return value from replace. Something like that:

```
path = path.replace('\\\\','\\', 1)
```

but I think you are using Java and I don't know if is the same, but try it

Comment: This is python, look at the tag. Als `while ... :` is obviously python.

Answer (score 1):

to replace 2 \ by one \ , you can do like that:

```
value = "C:\\\\Windows\\\\System32\\\\kernel32.dll"
print value.replace("\\\\", "\\")
```

gives me:

```
C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns a single backslash and can be compared to output from os.getcwd()

```
path = path.replace('\\\\', '\\')
```