# How do you use Python to print a list of files from a CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I was hoping to use a CSV file with a list of file paths in one column and use Python to print the actual files.

We are using Window 7 64-bit.

---

I have got it to print a file directly:

```
import os
os.startfile(r'\\fileserver\Sales\Sell Sheet1.pdf, 'print')
```

The issues comes in when I bring in the CSV file. I think I'm not formatting it correctly because I keep getting:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError2] The system cannot find the file specified: "['\\\\fileserver\\Sales\\Sell Sheet1']"

This is where I keep getting hung up:

```
import os
import csv
with open (r'\\fileserver\Sales\TestList.csv') as csv_file:
    TestList = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in TestList:
        os.startfile(str(row),'print')
```

My sample CSV file contains:

```
\\fileserver\Sales\SellSheet1
\\fileserver\Sales\SellSheet2
\\fileserver\Sales\SellSheet3
```

Is this an achievable goal?

Comment: Should those \\fileserver\Sales\SellSheetN entries have .pdf suffixes?

Comment: Can you include the full traceback instead of just the bottom line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove multiple backslashes from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916804/remove-multiple-backslashes-from-string)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using `str()` there. The CSV reader gives you a list of rows, and each row is a list of fields. Since you just want the first field, you should get that:

```
os.startfile(row[0], 'print')
```

Comment: further to this the OP should be confused about where the extra `['` and `']`are coming from in the error message