# Replace all spaces to dash in all my "url" object from my article model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I would like to replace all the spaces in my defined url objects from my Article model to "-". However, my code below doesn't seem to work.

```
def index(request):
    change_urls = Article.objects.all()
    for i in change_urls:
        i.url.replace(" ", "-")
        i.save()
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What's is the output you get?

Comment: my url still didn't change, it still has spaces and no dashes.

Comment: `.replace(..)` creates a *new* string, it does not modify the string.

Comment: what should I do in order to modify my urls?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python str.replace does not actually modify the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44746300/python-str-replace-does-not-actually-modify-the-string)

Comment: Also see [Django bulk update with string replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21464918/django-bulk-update-with-string-replace) which should show how to do it entirely on the DB side.

Answer (score 1):

`.replace(..)` creates a *new* string, it does not modify the string. You can thus work with:

```
def index(request):
    change_urls = list(Article.objects.all())
    for i in change_urls:
        i.url = i.url.replace(' ', '-')
    Article.objects.bulk_update(change_urls, fields=('url',))
    # …
```

But if you want to "slugify", please use the [**`slugify(…)`** function <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify).

Comment: I got this error: QuerySet.bulk_update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fields'