# Prepend a string in Python

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, prepend

I'm trying to prepend zeros to each number in a list if it isn't a the necessary number of digits.

```
    lst = ['1234','2345']
    for x in lst:
        while len(x) < 5:
            x = '0' + x
    print(lst)
```

Ideally this would print ['012345', '02345']

Comment: A better example would be if `lst = ['1234', '23456']`. How do we `print(lst)` and get `['01234', '23456']`

Comment: Ultimately it was a combination of the answers that was successful.
`lst = ['1234','2345']
newlst = []

for i in lst:
    i = i.zfill(5)
    newlst.append(i)

print(newlst)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, it was a combination of the answers that did the job.

```
lst = ['1234','2345']
newlst = []

for i in lst:
    i = i.zfill(5)
    newlst.append(i)

print(newlst)
```

I apologize if my example wasn't clear. Thank you to all who offered answers!

Comment: Nice work, good for finding out the solution, is a plus one i think :)

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`zfill`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill):

> Pad a numeric string s on the left with zero digits until the given
>   width is reached

```
lst = ['1234','2345']
[s.zfill(5) for s in lst]
# ['01234', '02345']
```

Or use [`format`](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align) method with *padding and alignment*:

```
["{:0>5}".format(s) for s in lst]
# ['01234', '02345']
```

Comment: That's a great idea indeed, perfect for this case... I like it, plus one

Answer (score 3):

You code doesn't do the job because strings in python are immutable, see this for more info [Why doesn't calling a Python string method do anything unless you assign its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out)

You could you enumerate in this case like this:

```
lst = ['1234','2345', "23456"]
for i, l in enumerate(lst):
  if len(l) < 5:
    lst[i] = '0' + l
print(lst)
```

> ['01234', '02345', '23456']

Comment: Hi Damian, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to account for cases where a list item is long enough. I apologize for giving a poor example.

Comment: Sorry @ Damian, I should have given a better example. Suppose `lst = ['1234', '23456']` I was trying to get `['01234', '23456']` . The second number is not affected because it is sufficiently long.

Comment: @Coby aaaah now I get it, I will update the answer and let me know :)

Comment: @Coby I think that's what you are looking at, and I did it this way to try to not modify your code so much. I hope it helps, don't forget voting and accepting if it was helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list comprehension like this:

```
>>> ['0' * (5-len(x)) + x for x in lst]
['01234', '02345']
```

Or a `list` + `map` try:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: '0' * (5-len(x)) + x, lst))
['01234', '02345']
```

Comment: a little twisted but I like it, it does the job :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
>>> lst = ['1234','2345']
>>> lst = ['0' * (5 - len(i)) + i for i in lst]
>>> print(lst)
['01234', '02345']
```