# Facing issue while replacing string of a file in Python

Tags: python

Here is my code snippet. What am I doing wrong? Not able to replace the string.

```
f = open("template.html", "r")
 lines = f.read()
 string = '''<header > 
 <h2 align="center"> High </h2> 
 <h4> </h4> 
 </header> '''
 if string in lines:
    print lines
    lines.replace("<header >", "<header style=background-color:red >")
    print lines
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't calling a Python string method do anything unless you assign its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out)

Comment: Python strings are *immutable* - read-only if you like.  So no string methods can alter the string in place, they have to return a new string.

Comment: @user3640472, it is working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

After you use `replace` you need to save it back to the variable.

**Ex:**

```
lines = lines.replace("<header >", "<header style=background-color:red >")
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace` method *returns* a copy of the string in which the occurrences of old have been replaced with new, optionally restricting the number of replacements to max.

So you need to update your `lines` variable's value. Python strings are *immutable* like in another programming languages like C#, Java, Javascript, PHP, etc.

```
lines = lines.replace("<header >", "<header style=background-color:red >")
```