# Eliminate numbers between 1 and 100 present in list

Tags: python

I have written a code that should input numbers from the user and report back the numbers from 1 to 100 that are missing from their input.

My code is below which doesn't work:

```
num_list = []

number = input('Enter numbers (remember a space): ')

number.split()

num_list.append(number)

for i in range(1, 101):
  if i in num_list:
    continue
  else:
    print(i, end =', ')
```

The code outputs all the numbers from 1 to 100 but doesn't exclude the numbers.

Note: The code has to exclude all the numbers entered not only one number.

E.g. if the user inputted 1 2 3 4 the output should start from 5 and list the numbers through to 100.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't calling a Python string method do anything unless you assign its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out)

Comment: This is a great time to learn how to debug. Try printing out the values of variables at various points in the code and make sure it matches your expectations.

Comment: It would be better to use a `set` rather than a `list` if you're only using it to test for membership.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three of problems

1) your are not saving the returned list from split method

```
result = number.split()
```

2) Use `extend` instead of `append`

```
num_list.extend(result)
```

3) By default `input` will read everything as string, you need to convert them into `int` from `string` after splitting, below is example using `List Comprehensions`

```
result = [int(x) for x in number.split()]
```

**append :** Will just add an item to the end of the list

So in you case after appending user input your list will be

```
num_list.append(number) #[[1,2,3,4,5]] so use extend
```

**extend :** Extend the list by appending all the items from the iterable.

```
num_list.append(number) #[1,2,3,4,5]
```

**Note :** If the `num_list` empty you can directly use `result` from `split` method, no need of `extend`

Comment: There's no reason to use `extend` with an empty list. Just assign the result of splitting directly to `num_list`.