# replacing every 4 word string in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, replace, user-defined-functions

```
def abc(filename):
    infile = open(filename, 'r+')
    read = infile.read()
    lst = read.split()

    for i in lst:
        if len(i) == 4:
            i.replace(i, 'abcd')
            print(i)

abc('question 4.txt')
```

I want to replace 4 character strings in my text file but apparently this is not happening. Everything seems to be working fine but the replacing function is not responding.

Comment: [Why doesn't calling a Python string method do anything unless you assign its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9189172/1324033)

Comment: @cocool97 - Just realised that

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```
 for n, i in enumerate(lst):
    if len(i) == 4:
        lst[n] = 'abcd'
```