# Capitalize a char on iteration, like a marquee in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I saw a screencast on youtube were this guy was using something called metasploit. And every time that program was loading, a welcome screen was presented. Every char was capitalized like a wave running from left to right, like a marquee function.

And as a python noob I thought that would be pretty simple to recreate :) but boi was I wrong!

This is what I´v got:

```
import time
import os

string = "this is a test"

count = 0
kuk = list(string)
for i in range(len(string)):
    os.system('clear')
    if i == count:
        string[i].upper()
    print(string)
    count += 1
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

The problem seems that I don't know how to iterate the `kuk`variable, and print the list like a string (if that makes sense) and at the same time manipulate the char to `upper()` on each iteration.

### The expected result should be:

First iteration: This is a test

Second: tHis is a test

third: thIs is a test

fourth: thiS is a test

....

Comment: your line `string[i].upper()` have no effect because the function returns the capitalized string and doesn't change the original

Answer (score 3):

Short approach using `sys.stdout.write` with *carriage return* `\r` (allows to overwrite the current line in-place) and `enumerate` feature:

```
import time
from sys import stdout

string = "this is a test"
for i, c in enumerate(string):
    if c:
        stdout.write('\r' + string[:i] + c.upper() + string[i+1:])
    time.sleep(0.3)
```

- `if c:` condition allows to skip redundant slicing and indexing on whitespace chars
- if you're on Python >= 3.6 the currently printed line can be built with flexible `f-string` style: `stdout.write(f'\r{string[:i]}{c.upper()}{string[i+1:]}')`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a generator function in combination with `enumerate`:

```
string = "this is a test"

def marquee(some_string):
    for idx, char in enumerate(some_string):
        yield some_string[0:idx] + char.upper() + some_string[idx + 1:]

for s in marquee(string):
    print(s)
```

Which yields

```
This is a test
tHis is a test
thIs is a test
thiS is a test
this is a test
this Is a test
this iS a test
this is a test
this is A test
this is a test
this is a Test
this is a tEst
this is a teSt
this is a tesT
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do something like this is to keep track of the index that you want to capitalize, and print in three stages:

1. The part of the string *before* what you want to capitalize
2. The character you want to capitalize, converted to uppercase
3. The part of the string *after* what you want to capitalize

We can use string slicing to do this.

```
import os, time
string = "this is a test"
count = 0
while True:
   # clear screen
   os.system('clear')
   # print each of the three section
   first_part = string[:count]
   second_part = string[count].upper()
   third_part = string[count + 1:]
   print(first_part + second_part + third_part)
   # increment to the next index. Once we reach the end of the string, wrap around.
   count = (count + 1) % len(string)
   time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Python strings are immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out). This means the line `string[i].upper()` does not modify `string`.

You can use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation) instead.

For example:

```
myString = "this is a test"
for i in range(len(myString)):
    os.system('clear')
    print(myString[:i] + myString[i].upper() + myString[i+1:])
    time.sleep(0.3)
#This is a test
#tHis is a test
#thIs is a test
#thiS is a test
#this is a test
#this Is a test
#this iS a test
#this is a test
#this is A test
#this is a test
#this is a Test
#this is a tEst
#this is a teSt
#this is a tesT
```

This doesn't skip whitespace, but you can easily add that logic if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slicing:

```
s = 'abc'

for idx in range(len(s)):
    print(f'{s[:idx]}{s[idx:].title()}')
```

Output:

```
Abc
aBc
abC
```