# Replace a specific value in a string in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to replace a specific values in a long string. Is it possible to do this with replace function in python?

a snipit of the string is:

```
'rh':0, 'rp':0, 't':'b.nan','rh':1, 'rp':1, 't':'b.nan'
```

my snipit string should look like

```
'rh':0, 'rp':0, 't':b.nan,'rh':1, 'rp':1, 't':b.nan
```

i'm trying to replace the `'b.nan'` to `b.nan` but it doesn't work.

The code i'm using:

```
a.replace("'b.nan'", "b.nan")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out

Comment: Error im getting: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: So `a` is a dictionary and not a string? Please update the question with that information. Try to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can index strings like arrays:

```
string = "hello"
print(string[1])
```

this prints 'e'

You could try finding the index and then replacing it as such