# How to replace "\" in a string with "/" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, replace

Let's assume I have a string:

```
a="qihdkasf\sdgbsdf\rgsdg"
```

I want to replace `"\"` in string `a` with `"/"` in python.
I do know that while printing `"\"`, we need to write it as `print("\\")`. Considering that, 
I tried doing something like this, as shown below:

```
a.replace("\\","/")
```

but, it doesn't seem to be working!

Any help on the matter will be really appreciated.

Comment: Don't seem working : explain, always ;) Also you have not a *\\* and a *r* which is a *\r* a special char, you cant replace the single \

Comment: well, did you really define `a="qihdkasf\sdgbsdf\rgsdg"` as you've shown? because the issue is, `\r` has a meaning, so that became a character. also, this code *is* working fine for what it's suppsoed to do

Comment: Also, i bet [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out) is your issue

Comment: @ParitoshSingh, Yup! The thread that you posted, solved the issue! Thank you so much! I am pretty careless and I shouldn't have made such a rookie mistake :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use:

```
r"qihdkasf\sdgbsdf\rgsdg".replace('\\', '/')
```

output:

```
qihdkasf/sdgbsdf/rgsdg
```