# There is a problem in understanding one of the python data type

Tags: python

```
x = "hello, world"
print(x.replace("h","j")
```

so from this code you can change the letter h to j so that means it is mutable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't calling a Python string method do anything unless you assign its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so that means it is mutable

No, Python strings are not mutable. `str.replace` (and any other string method) return a new string.

If strings were mutable then the following code

```
x = "hello, world"
x.replace("h","j")
print(x)
```

Would output `jello, world` (which it does not).

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt mean that string is mutable it means that we are creating a new string in the `replace` method.

```
>>> a= "ababa"
>>> id(a)
48421600L
>>> id(a.replace('a','c'))
48419776L
>>>
```

as you can see from the id of the strings, that they are two different strings. Or you can use the `is` operator for comparison also.

Comment: there are unique during their lifetimes, which is the case for this comparison so i dont see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in python.

```
>>> x = 'hello, world'
>>> x
[OUT]: 'hello, world'
>>> id(x)
[OUT]: 4400926320
>>> x = x.replace('h','j')
>>> x
[OUT]: 'jello, world'
>>> id(x)
[OUT]: 4402216304
```

When you you try to modify a value of a string object it points to a new string with different location in the memory as strings are immutable.
id(x) returns the memory address of x.