# In python how to search and replace in strings?

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace

In python how to search and replace in strings?

This is my code, I want to replace `'python'` with `'Java'`

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
    
find_it = "python"
repl_it = "Java"
text = "python is amazing. I love python, it is the best language. python is the most readable language."
    
if text.find(find_it):
    text = text.replace(find_it, repl_it)
    
print(text)
```

The output is still the same:

```sh
python is amazing. I love python, it is the best language. python is the most readable language.
```

How to replace words in a string?

Comment: ``text.find(find_it)`` returns the *position* of the search string, which in this case is 0 – aka boolean False.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189193/11915595](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189193/11915595)?

Comment: @JorgeMorgado these are not duplicates. OP does reassign the call of `replace`. The problem is that it is not being called to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.find` returns the index of the beginning of the first match.

In your case, it is `0`, so the `if` condition will be evaluated as `False` hence `.replace` is not being called (if you will remove `python` from the start of the string your code will work).

You don't need the check at all. `str.replace` will not raise an error if it does not find what to replace.

```
find_it = "python"
repl_it = "Java"
text = "python is amazing. I love python, it is the best language. python is the most readable language."
text = text.replace(find_it, repl_it)
print(text)
# Java is amazing. I love Java, it is the best language. Java is the most readable language.
```

Comment: Oh! OK. But how do I find if the word exists in a string? I only want to replace it if I find it in a string, else I want to keep the original string as it is.

Comment: @KumarPrasad Again, if the string you are replacing is not in the string, the string will not be modified. You don't need to worry about it

Comment: @KumarPrasad To find a substring in a string you can use `if find_it in text:`.

Answer (score 0):

You have your code wrapped in the conditional `if text.find(find_it)`
The problem with that is that returns the first index of the text you are looking for. Which in your case is 0 as your text starts with python. Your conditional is retunring 0 and then evaluating to false. The find method does not return a boolean if text was found but an index of where it was

```
find_it = "python"
repl_it = "Java"
text = "python is amazing. I love python, it is the best language. python is the most readable language."


text = text.replace(find_it, repl_it)

print(text)
```

This code works just fine