# Python replace method

Tags: python, methods, replace

I write the code below but replace method is not working.

code:

```
courses = input("Please enter the courses you have taken previously with letter grades: ")
courses.replace("M","X")
print(courses)
```

Please enter the courses you have taken previously with letter grades:

```
MATH101:A;SPS101:B;CS201:B+;HIST191:D;CS204:F;CS210:S:
MATH101:A;SPS101:B;CS201:B+;HIST191:D;CS204:F;CS210:S:
```

Comment: The `.replace()` method does not modify the string object. It returns a modified copy. You have to reassign it to `courses`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't calling a Python string method do anything unless you assign its output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-python-string-method-do-anything-unless-you-assign-its-out)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  Please read the method specifications before posting a related question.

Answer (score 1):

replace won't mutate the string in place. [str.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

```
courses = courses.replace("M", "X")
```

Answer (score 1):

The replace method doesn't replace the text in original string, it returns a new one.
What you need to do is -

```
courses = courses.replace("M", "X")
print(courses)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
courses = courses.replace("M","X")
```

Just like 12944qwerty says, You need to reassign into courses