# python .lower() is not working

Tags: python, lowercase

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but the function .lower() in my python code is not working!

It's a sily code, but it does not lower de cases of the word:

```
score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
         "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
         "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
         "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
         "x": 8, "z": 10}

def scrabble_score(word):
    word.lower()
    print word
    total =0
    for i in word:
        total += score[i]
    return total

print scrabble_score('Helix')
```

some help?

Comment: try `word = word.lower()`

Comment: It should be `word = word.lower()`

Comment: `word = word.lower()` as strings are immutable.

Comment: It should've been obvious the error seeing as you printed word after you call `word.lower()`

Comment: You have a lot of answers here, but none really explains why this happens. It's because python strings are immutable. That means you can't change them in-place, just make a changed copy of it and assign it to some other variable, or itself. Python has mutable variables, i.e. lists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to assign the result of `lower()` back to word as strings are [immutable](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-are-python-strings-immutable):

```
In [152]:

score = {"a": 1, "c": 3, "b": 3, "e": 1, "d": 2, "g": 2, 
         "f": 4, "i": 1, "h": 4, "k": 5, "j": 8, "m": 3, 
         "l": 1, "o": 1, "n": 1, "q": 10, "p": 3, "s": 1, 
         "r": 1, "u": 1, "t": 1, "w": 4, "v": 4, "y": 4, 
         "x": 8, "z": 10}

def scrabble_score(word):
    word = word.lower() #<------ here assign back
    print(word)
    total =0
    for i in word:
        total += score[i]
    return total

print(scrabble_score('Helix'))

helix
15
```

See related: [Why are Python strings immutable? Best practices for using them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680080/why-are-python-string-immutable-best-practices-of-using-them)

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
word = word.lower()
```

because `lower()` doesn't modify original string

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not assigning value to word after converting it into lowercase. So it still has the old value which is "Helix"

```
word = word.lower()
```