# Stemming full strings on Python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stemming

I need to perform stemming on portuguese strings.  To do so, i'm tokening the string using nltk.word_tokenize() function a then stemming each word individually. After that, I rebuild the string. It's working, but not performing well. How can i make it faster? The string length is about 2 million words.

```
    tokenAux=""
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(portugueseString)
        for token in tokens:
            tokenAux = token
            tokenAux = stemmer.stem(token)    
            textAux = textAux + " "+ tokenAux
    print(textAux)
```

Sorry for bad english and thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string` is immutable so, it is not good practice to update string every time if the string is long. The [link here](https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/) explains various ways to concatenate string and shows performance analysis. And since, the iteration is done only once, it is good to choose `generator expression` over `list comprehension`. For details you can look into [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension) . Instead in this case, using `generator expression` with `join` can be helpful:

Using `my_text` for long string: `len(my_text) -> 444399`

Using `timeit` to compare:

```
%%timeit
tokenAux=""
textAux=""
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(my_text)
for token in tokens:
    tokenAux = token
    tokenAux = stemmer.stem(token)    
    textAux = textAux + " "+ tokenAux
```

Result:

```
1 loop, best of 3: 6.23 s per loop
```

Using `generator expression` with `join`:

```
%%timeit 
' '.join(stemmer.stem(token) for token in nltk.word_tokenize(my_text))
```

Result:

```
1 loop, best of 3: 2.93 s per loop
```

Comment: @yuridamata Great! `Happy Coding.`

Answer (score 1):

String objects are immutable in Python. Look into your code:

```
textAux = ""
for token in tokens:
    # something important ...
    textAux = textAux + " "+ tokenAux
```

Every time you create a new string in a loop and assign it to `textAux` variable. This is not efficient.

I would store `tokenAux` elements in a list and just join them in the very end. See the example:

```
tokenAux = []  # we declare list for storing tokens
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(portugueseString)
for token in tokens:
    tokenAux = token
    tokenAux = stemmer.stem(token)    
    textAux.append(tokenAux)  # we add new token into the resulting list

result = " ".join(textAux)  # join list using space as separator
print(result)
```

Compare the performance and share it with us :)

Useful links:

- [Why are Python strings immutable? Best practices for using them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680080/why-are-python-strings-immutable-best-practices-for-using-them)
- [Explain Python .join()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876191/explain-python-join)

Answer (score 0):

You could read the string in as a text file and then perform the necessary operations to stem each word using [PySpark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html). This will allow you to perform your operations in parallel.

You can also use the [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: Does PySpark really have a built-in Portuguese stemmer?

Comment: I'm not sure. There's no reason why PySpark couldn't be used in conjunction with NLTK. @lenz